# How do I format the logic for 3 conditions and use a previous condition as well?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, logic

*NOT ASKING FOR ANYONE TO WRITE THE PROGRAM FOR ME*

I am having trouble understanding how to setup the logic for a program given these following conditions:

- For every day late up to and including 7 days, the late fee is $0.10/day
- After 7 days, for every day late up to and including 90 days, the late fee is $0.20/day.

> (Example: a book returned 10 days late incurs a late fee of $1.30 late fee, $0.10 for each of the first 7 days plus $0.20  for each of the remaining 3 days)
>
> > This is where I am having issues. I am not sure how to include the previous condition along with this one. My best guess is some sort of nested loop or an elseif containing this condition and something about the last one?

- After 90 days, an unreturned book is considered lost. All late fees are waived, but the borrower is charged the cost of the book, plus a $10 restocking fee.

This is my best attempt, but I'm not sure this is the most efficient logic:

```
    if (daysLate > 90)
    {
        costDue = bookPrice + 10;
    }
    else if (daysLate <= 90)
    {
        costDue = (7*0.10) * (daysLate*0.20);
    }
    else if (daysLate <= 7)
    {
        costDue = daysLate*0.10;
    }
    else
    {
        IO.reportBadInput();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second condition should be changed, otherwise the third `if` won't be reached. Also the third condition should be changed to check if the `daysLate` variable is greater or equal to zero:

```
if (daysLate > 90)
{
    costDue = bookPrice + 10;
}
else if (daysLate >= 7)
{
    costDue = (7*0.10) + ((daysLate - 7) * 0.20);  // change here
}
else if (daysLate >= 0)
{
    costDue = daysLate*0.10;
}
else
{
    IO.reportBadInput();
}
```

Comment: Should be `costDue = (7*0.10) + ((daysLate - 7) * 0.20);`

Answer (score 1):

```
   if (daysLate > 90)
    {
        costDue = bookPrice + 10;
    }
    else if (daysLate > 7 && daysLate <= 90)
    {
        costDue = (7*0.10) * (daysLate*0.20);
    }
    else
    {
        costDue = daysLate*0.10;
    }
```

Simply update the second clause and drop that last one, that'll straighten it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (daysLate > 90)
{
    costDue = bookPrice + 10;
}
else if (daysLate >= 0)
{
    costDue = daysLate * 0.10;
    if (daysLate > 7) {
        costDue += (daysLate - 7) * 0.10;
    }
} else {
    IO.reportBadInput();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

addition to all previous answers - the calculation for mid-term (between 7 days and 90) should have an addition instead of multiplication `(7*0.10) + (daysLate*0.20);` or even  `1.30 + (daysLate*0.20);` (as the problem description suggests)

Answer (score 1):

When you use an if statement you have to make sure that it separates the cases that you want to keep separate. In your code, the first `else if` statement includes all instances where `daysLate <= 90`, so the second `else if` would never execute.

Also check your past 7 days due computation, its seems like you would be overcharging people for those first 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, while sacrificing readability a bit, and eliminating one else-if condition:

```
    if (daysLate > 90)  {
        costDue = bookPrice + 10;
    }
    else if (daysLate >= 0 && daysLate <= 90) {
        costDue = Math.min(7, daysLate) * 0.10 + Math.max(daysLate - 7,  0) * 0.20;
    } 
    else {
        IO.reportBadInput();
    }
```